# Bootstrap4 Image not displaying on screen

Tags: html, image, bootstrap-4

I am trying to upload an image using the img tag. But even linking the image correctly it is not rendering on the screen
Here is the code.

```
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-6">
               <h2>MUSEUM OF CANDY</h2>
           </div>
           <div class="col-6">

<img class=" img-fluid" src="imgs/hand2.png" alt="handimage">
           </div>
       </div>
   </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source location might not be accurately defined. Please check through it once. If your alt information is visible. Then your problem is in source location.

Comment: location was the issue, I thought it was hand2.png, but it was hands2.png

Answer (score 0):

there is a space in the class at the beginning of "; maybe that's the problem :)